# How do I cause php-fpm to kill it's children after they are idle for a pre-defined period?

Tags: php, php-fpm

I've got several low traffic vhost'ed applications that I'd like to run on the same box, using something like this configuration:

```
[example.com]
listen       = /tmp/example.com.socket
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode  = 0666

user  = www-data
group = www-data

pm                   = dynamic ; scale children according to this rule
pm.max_requests      = 1000    ; respawn child after so many requests
pm.max_children      = 12      ; cap the total number of children thus
pm.start_servers     = 6       ; children created at daemon boot
pm.max_spare_servers = 2       ; maximum number of idling children
pm.min_spare_servers = 1       ; minimum number of idling children

pm.status_path       = /php_pool_example.com_status

request_terminate_timeout = 30s
request_slowlog_timeout   = 20s
slowlog                   = /var/www/com/example/logs/php-slow.log

catch_workers_output = yes

env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[TMP]      = /tmp
env[TMPDIR]   = /tmp
env[TEMP]     = /tmp

php_flag[display_errors]            = off
php_admin_value[error_log]          = /logs/php_err.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors]          = on
```

works okay, except that I'm not sure how to 'idle' a child so that php-fpm will kill it. The problem I'm seeing is that as I add more applications there exist ~6 idle php-fpm children per application, simply eating up RAM for no reason. Now, `request_terminate_timeout` will kill a child because of an over-long *request*, but not a child because of an overlong lack of requests. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) defines how to say there are too many or too little idle children, but is quiet on designation. If I've measured that a php-fpm child which hasn't served a request for 30 minutes should be considered 'idle' and killed, how do I inform php-fpm of this?

Comment: Smart of you to post on the highload-en group! I selfishly hope you get some good info there as this is relevant to my config as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next stable version of php-fpm should support an `ondemand` scheduler that will scale children up and down. To date, there is no recourse.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to report that as of today `ondemand` works perfectly. With ondemand you can set `pm.start_servers = 0` to stop idling processes:

```
pm = ondemand
pm.start_servers = 0
```